# Wrong scope for my nested classes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

At work I monitor a very large list of servers and websites associated with the application running on the servers. Generally each application has a cluster of servers behind it and roughly 6-10 different web-pages. So what I did was I created a Servers class that will take in a server's name(s) and control the urls that are associated with it. Now here's the part I'm struggling with. Each url is going to have two values associated with it: the physical url and the status of the url (online/offline). I came up with two ways of handling this: either I create a 2D array (or list) OR create a url subclass. The subclass method seemed like it would be better since I thought accessing all the methods of the subclass would be easy... Well right now I can't call them at all outside of the Servers class. This makes me think I have an issue with the scope of the classes/methods. Here's my Servers.cs code... What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Server
{
    public List<string> serverNames = new List<string>();
    public List<object> urlList = new List<object>();
    public string[][] urlArr = new string[1][];

    public Server()
    {

    }

    public Server(string nm)
    {
        serverNames.Add(nm);
    }

    public void setName(string newName)
    {
        serverNames.Add(newName);
    }

    public void addUrl(string newUrl)
    {
        Server.Url url = new Server.Url(newUrl);
        urlList.Add(url);
        url.SetStatus(false);
    }

    protected class Url
    {
        public string url;
        public bool status;

        public Url()
        {
        }

        public Url(string URL)
        {
            url = URL;
        }

        public void SetStatus(bool stat)
        {
            status = stat;
        }

        public bool ReturnStatus()
        {
            return status;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I'm trying to call the Url class method ReturnStatus to see the status of that url. The problem is that the ReturnStatus method isn't available...

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    int length = serversList[0].urlList.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(serversList[0].urlList[i].ToString()+                             serversList[0].urlList[i].ReturnStatus());
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the `Url` class `public` if you want to call it from the outside?

Comment: It's kind of unclear what's the problem, you're never using `Server.Url` from anything that could be called "outside the `Server`" class in your code example. Can you show some code that's you want to work, is broken, and the errors you get?

Comment: Aside: you might want to use C# properties instead of methods like `SetStatus()` and `ReturnStatus()`. If nothing else they're the idiomatic approach. Also does `urlArr` do anything?

Comment: If the `Url` class is to be instantiated outside of the `Server` class then move it out of the `Server` class. If not but you don't want to be able to instantiate or manipulate instances of `Url` then declare methods that wrap the handling of the `Url` class and only manipulate it internally. Otherwise with a public constructor and a public class, you could create instances of `Url` that reside outside the `Server` scope. An example of expected usage always helps so can you add this?

Comment: I actually had the class public, but then switched it to protected just to see what that would do. No, `urlArr` doesn't do anything right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a `Url` class is definitely the right move here. It allows you flexibility and growth potential for if you end up needing to store more information in it (perhaps `LastGoodStatusTime` or some other reporting data). However, it looks like you probably don't want it to be an inner class. Just make it its own class, then everyone can have access to it.

Additionally, as one of the comments mentioned, the `Status` in the `Url` class would be better made as a property.

```
public class Server
{
    public List<string> serverNames = new List<string>();
    public List<object> urlList = new List<object>();
    public string[][] urlArr = new string[1][];

    public Server()
    {

    }

    public Server(string nm)
    {
        serverNames.Add(nm);
    }

    public void setName(string newName)
    {
        serverNames.Add(newName);
    }

    public void addUrl(string newUrl)
    {
        Server.Url url = new Server.Url(newUrl);
        urlList.Add(url);
        url.SetStatus(false);
    }
}

public class Url
{
    public string url;
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public Url()
    {
    }

    public Url(string URL)
    {
        url = URL;
    }
}
```

Note that if you strongly desire to go the route of keeping `Url` an inner class, you'll need to:

- Make it `public`
- Refer to `Url` in external classes as `Server.Url`, as in `var myUrl = new Server.Url("http://stackoverflow.com/");`

Comment: The idea behind having it as a sub class was to keep the server and url objects linked together. I might try creating an external class since that seems easier.. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What I ended up doing was seperating the two classes. Then when I create a new Server object, I also create a new Url object and put them both in a 2D array. That way it should be easy to reference the matching servers/urls.